# How to solve this SIGABRT related to NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This alone causes a SIGABRT break when I launch it. #MyScript# contains a simple loop running which provides an output of information that the rest of the application can read. Why oh why SIGABRT??

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
    task.launchPath = @"#MyScript#";
    [task launch];    // Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
}
```

Example #MyScript# that reproduces this error:

```
 while :; do clear; echo hi; sleep 1; done;
```

Comment: Where is `#MyScript#` located? Is it actually named `#MyScript#`?

Comment: Well you aren't sending an init message...

Comment: #MyScript# is located in the same directory as the object trying to run it. [NSTask new] sends the init message so that's not it.